# ColumnTransformer object has no attribute shape error

Tags: python-3.x, cox-regression

My data file (CSV) contains categorical and non-categorical variables. To perform cox proportional hazard (CPH) I applied `OneHotEncoder` on two categorical variables (study_category and patient_category). I am getting the following error on the line where I am trying to fit the CPH model. I am passing three parameters: dataframe, duration column (), event column() to `cph.fit()` method. I googled the error but could not found something useful. I am using CPH first time, any help to fix the issue will be appreciated.
Error:
`AttributeError: 'ColumnTransformer' object has no attribute 'shape'`

My python code:

```
def meth():
 dataset = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/XYZ/CTR_Project/CPH.csv")
 dataset=dataset.loc[:, 
 ['study_Category','patient_Category','Diff_time','Events']]
    
 X=dataset.loc[:,['study_Category','patient_Category','Diff_time','Events']]

 colm_transf=make_column_transformer((OneHotEncoder(), 
 ['study_Category','patient_Category']),remainder='passthrough')

 colm_transf.fit_transform(X)
 cph= CoxPHFitter()

 cph.fit(colm_transf,duration_col='Diff_time', event_col='Events')
 cph.print_summary()
```